# How to make a text and graphic clickable in pixi5?

Tags: pixi.js

```
  const font = new PIXI.Text('TJXY');
        font.anchor.set(0.5);
        font.position.set(renderer.screen.width / 2, renderer.screen.height / 2);
        font.interactive = true;
        font.buttonMode = true;
        font.on('pointerdown', function () {
            font.scale.y *= 1.25;
        });
        stage.addChild(font);
```

that didn't work.but the v5 doc suggested that it's possible, no error show in console.

Comment: In what way this doesn't work, because it should work, and indeed I tested it and it worked;

Answer (score 0):

```
var basicText = new PIXI.Text('Basic text in pixi');
basicText.x = 585;
basicText.y = 90;
basicText.interactive = true;
basicText.buttonMode = true;
basicText.on('pointerdown', onButtonDown);//Action Listener

function onButtonDown() {
  console.log("What you do :)");
}
```

You can try this sample , it's works * pixi.js - v5.1.5 * version